# what is regex for odd length series of a known character in a string?

Tags: regex

That is a regex that would match:

```
stringAstring => A
stringAAAstring => AAA
stringAAAAAstring => AAAAA
[... and so on...]
```

But wouldn't match:

```
stringAAstring => null
stringAAAAstring => null
stringAAAAAAstring => null
```

Comment: Is the character known beforehand (e.g., "A") or should it match any character that is repeated an odd number of times? (If the latter, then any individual character not followed or preceded by the same character would match.)

Comment: character is known beforehand (I've edited title now.)

Comment: There are cases in which one simply shouldn't try to solve something with (only) a regexp :) The regexp from the accepted answer will require documentation to be remotely understandable and will probably not be faster than a simpler regexp + checking the length of the match[citation needed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the regex flavor you're using supports look-arounds, this should work:

```
(?<!A)(AA)*A(?!A)
```

`(AA)*A` matches an odd number of `'A'`s and the `(?<!A)` asserts that it should not be preceded by an `'A'` and `(?!A)` asserts it should not be followed by an `'A'`.

Comment: Thanks, it works for utf-8 too: `(?<!中)(?:中中)*中(?!中)` , I've added a `?:` in the middle to not needlessly return double character.